# How to center one table while having another table centered in its right margin

Tags: html, css

I want to place two HTML tables besides each other, having one centered in the webpage and the other one centered within the right margin of the of the first table.
`myTable` is supposed to be centered and `keypadTable` is a smaller table in the right margin of `myTable`

Currently, `myTable` is not at the centre of the overall webpage and `keypadTable` is just floating as expected
Right now:

```
[       (center)    (right)]
```

What I want:

(eg. (center) is 9space from each "[]" and (right) is 1space from (centre) and closing bracket

```
[         (center) (right) ]
```

```html
<table id="keypadTable" style="float: right;width: 300px; height:
          341px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
  <tbody align="center"> </tbody>
</table>

<table id="mytable" style="float:center; text-align: right; width: 1014px; height:
          341px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
```

Comment: Protips: 1) Floats are a dated, troublesome layout technique. Don't used them. 2)  Don't use inline styles. They're a pain for all involved. Use custom CSS classes. 3) Use classes for CSS, not IDs, so that it's reusable.

Comment: Your requirements don't address the natural flow of tables. What content will yours have? Which takes space precedence? Please provide a complete example so we can provide answers with confidence. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Answer (score 1):

you want to use flex.  create another invisible element the same size as your right table to get the spacing to work.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  
  
  <table class='hidden'>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: since when `space-evenly` centers the content?

Comment: since the row is symmetric.  That's why we use visibility:hidden as oppose to display:none. Doesn't it look centered?

Comment: Oh, I see that my edit was faulty. Apologies. Still, this requires duplicating the third table and all its content, which isn't ideal.

Comment: maybe not ideal but the easiest way to do this.  How would you do it?